# Can not run add-migration or update-database after updating Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, package-manager-console

I'm working on a solution that has multiple projects, one of these projects is for generating migration code, every thing was working fine until I updated the VS to the latest release 15.5.7.

Now when I try to run the Add-migration it does nothing, no code generate, no error messages, just load the prompt again like below:

[image]

Please advice as I'm stuck and can not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem, I had to first update some packages

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

Then Edit your .csproj file by adding this line

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
```